# Recycler view getting scrolled inside the header collapsable toolbar sometimes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have my coordinator layout some thing like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collappbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
            />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
            />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/gray" />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Problem is ,the recycler view which i set inside view pager,some times scrolls inside the collapsable header,even when the header is not collapsed,and also collapsing is not smooth.